# Is index an Constraint in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, constraints

Few Documentation says index is an type of Constraint, but other docs doesn't included index in an constraint section, so it is doubtful, whether index is an constraint or not?.

Can anyone share your points regarding it...?

```
Constraint
```

Comment: *Few Documentation says index is an type of Constraint* Either you understand incorrectly or this documentation is wrong. Index is not an object of relational theory at all. It is storage object which increases operations effectiveness.

Comment: @Akina check these docs... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-constraints.htm https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp

Comment: I agree with Akina.  But so what if an "index" is _called_ a "constraint"?  Anyway, neither link is to the MySQL official documentation.  Tutorialspoint is someone's very abbreviated reference manual, and to some extent, tutorial.  I glanced on some other pages -- I quibble with some things, but don't see any dangerously erronous statements.

Comment: w3schools is very terse and tries to be agnostic to the versions.  I spotted at least one syntax error for MySQL (that would work in some other brand.  So, be cautious about trusting that site.

Comment: @RickJames Me too, but get confused "whether index is an constraint or not?" after looking those docs.

Comment: 'The SQL standard specifies that all types of constraints (primary key, unique index, foreign key, check) ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html. I can see why - primary and unique keys constrain/limit the values that can be entered as do foreign keys. see also https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest/chapters/20.html#constraint-type-unique-constraint

Comment: If you want to point me to the line "INDEX − Used to create and retrieve data from the database very quickly." then I can say that it is placed into constraints list errorneously. It must be placed separately. This is common unaccuracy.

Comment: At least two types of constraints - Primary key and unique - are *implemented* via indexes, but calling indexes constraints is to get things the wrong way around.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the real question behind that question? Is there anything special to knowing how this "constraint" is handled internally?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL creates indexes for three types of constraint:

- Primary key constraint create a unique index.
- Unique constraints create a unique index.
- Foreign key constraints create an index on the referencing columns.

The first two are common in all databases.

Is an index a constraint?  Not really, but a unique index has the same effect as a unique constraint on the same columns.  So, you can think of a unique index as implementing a unique constraint.  That said, I think the causality is better understood the other way:  a unique constraint is implemented using a unique index.

Comment: `a unique constraint is implemented using a unique index.` Makes sense considering that DB engine needs to check all the data to confirm if the value already exists. Using an index should speed up the process.

Answer (score 3):

1. An index is a schema object
2. Indexes are special lookup tables that the database search engine can use to speed up data retrieval. Simply put, an index is a pointer to data in a table. An index in a
   the database is very similar to an index in the back of a book.
3. Indexes are used to retrieve data from the database more quickly than otherwise. The users cannot see the indexes, they are just used to speed up searches/queries.
4. Indexes are automatically created when PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints are defined on table columns. For example, when you create a table with a UNIQUE constraint, Database Engine automatically creates a nonclustered index. If you configure a PRIMARY KEY, Database Engine automatically creates a clustered index, unless a clustered index already exists. When you try to enforce a PRIMARY KEY constraint on an existing table and a clustered index already exists on that table, SQL Server enforces the primary key using a nonclustered index.

Comment: Another thing to note (in MySQL):  `PRIMARY KEY` is `UNIQUE` is an `INDEX` == `KEY`.

Comment: @RickJames Primary key entity consists from 2 parts. First part is constraints pack: UNIQUE constraint + NOT NOLL constraint. Second part is an index which allows to check these constraints effectively. Formally these constraints may be checked without an index, is it? but this process will be too slow - so index creation/usage is made/defined compulsory.

Comment: This answer doesn't contain any connection to the main question about "constraints", it doesn't even mention this word

Comment: Also, the PK is 'clustered' with the data (for InnoDB).  MyISAM does not cluster; other vendors have clustering as an option.